# Generated exe with gradle launch4j plugin not starts

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, launch4j

I tried to generate the exe using the gradle plugin gradle-launch4j with the following configuration of the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.6'
    id 'application'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // lib via maven
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.15'
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.28.0'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main'
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'Main'
}

launch4j {
    mainClassName = 'Main'
    outfile = 'Gymnasium.exe'
    icon = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/view/img/icona.ico"
    jreMinVersion = "1.8.0"
}
```

Exe is generated but trying to run, it not starts. I noticed that it starts  if I launch it from terminal using java -jar Gymnasium.exe command.
Is there something of wrong in my configuration? I tried to search if someone had a similiar issue but I didn't find anything.

Note: If I try to generate the exe from Launch4j application it works perfectly.